# What's the difference when using gulp and opening index.html directly in this case?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am new on gulp. I am reading this code: https://github.com/PatrickO10/meetUp right now. I tried to clone it on my desktop and open the index.html. I found it works well. But there are still some steps to install it on that page, like this.

`Run npm install` in command line to get the required

type `gulp` in the command line and it will launch a locally hosted page

The account I signed up when I open index.html directly can still be used when using gulp. I just don't know what's the difference if I just open index.html and use gulp.

Comment: When you open the file in your browser, the browser is going through the file system. (Without looking) The gulp command launches a web server, which handles the requests. So instead of going through the file system, the browser sends the request to the web server, which in turn fetches the file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) is a build utility for Javascript codebases. It reads instructions from a gulpfile that defines a set of build steps. The [gulpfile for this repository](https://github.com/PatrickO10/meetUp/blob/master/gulpfile.js) defines some build steps that include compiling the CSS and Javascript, and linting the Javascript. You can read more at the Gulp documentation I linked to. When you open the index.html file directly, these files are not built, so the application won't run properly - it'll be missing CSS and Javascript.